# MySQL doesn't update records from two databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating the records of one table from one db into another.

Now when I run the query it is working but it shows that zero record have been updated.

However, there are more than 2000 records which are matched. I want to update the table `limeappl_store_test`:

```
UPDATE 
  limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value, 
  limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import 
SET 
  limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value.quantity = limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import.qty
WHERE 
  limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value.ob_sku = limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import.item
```

Comment: Your query looks good, 0 rows could be updated because all rows have matching quantities.

Comment: it sku is matched, then it must be updated ?

Comment: Add AND limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value.quantity != limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import.qty  to your SELECT statement and check how many rows you get.

Comment: 3400  records are there

Answer (score 0):

You need to join

```
UPDATE limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value
JOIN limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import
  ON limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value.ob_sku = limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import.item
SET limeappl_store_test.oc_product_option_value.quantity = limeappl_storesync.sys_product_import.qty
```